# Disallow-todo-tests on PHPUnit 7.5.6

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to use the option `phpunit --disallow-todo-tests` to ignore some tests that needs to be wrote.

[Documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.5/textui.html)

> **--disallow-todo-tests**
>   Does not execute tests which have the @todo annotation in its docblock.

I have tried many way. Here's some example:

```
/**
 * @test
 * @todo: implement this
 */
public function my_random_test(): void
{
    $this->assertTrue(false);
}

/**
 * @todo: implement this
 */
public function test_my_another_random_test(): void
{
    $this->assertTrue(false);
}


public function test_this_one_is_also_random(): void
{
    /**
     * @todo: implement this
     */
    $this->assertTrue(false);
}


/**
 * @test
 * @todo implement this
 */
public function another_test(): void
{
    $this->assertTrue(false);
}
```

Also wrote without `:`, `@` or like that `@todo-annotated` ... Nothing works. I alway get the failures.

I have a **phpunit.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@todo` should not be followed by a colon. That's why phpunit doesn't find your todo annotations.

http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/todo.html